# VBA - Copy & Paste Transpose?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy and paste transpose but sort them

The data I want to copy and transpose:

```
A1 00001
A1 00002

B1 00001
B1 00002
```

How I want it to Copy and transpose to:

```
A1       A1
00001    00002

B1       B1
00001    00002
```

The code that I am using at the moment:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1000").Copy

Sheets("POSITION").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But it only copy and transpose to:

```
A1       A1       B1       B1
00001    00002    00001    00002
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This is not a simple transpose issue... Is it possible to have more occurrences in terms of A1, B1, C1 etc. or `0001`, `0002`, `0003` etc. Then, can they also  be not sorted, no blanc rows separators etc.?

Comment: I am really new to vba, in terms of A1, B1, C1 etc. all the reference are different each time  but it will already be sorted into category A1,B1,C1 etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they will be sorted in categories (for the method I have in my mind...)., but is it possible that each such unique keys (A1, A2 etc.) to have different numbers of items (`0001`, `0002`, `0003` etc. for A1 and only `0001' for B1)?

Comment: Yes, unique keys will have different numbers of items. I was just wondering if you could just copy & paste transpose line by line on each cell from `A1:B1000?` and paste it on column `D` downward?

Comment: This way is completely ineficient... I will prepare an answer. To be fast for even a huge range to be processed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, if you won't mind putting comments to explain how it works. I would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I started working but I also have something urgent to finish...

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It should be very fast, using arrays and a dictionary to allow it working mostly in memory. It places the processed result in another array and drop its result at the end of the code. No need to group categories! The code is able to extract the unique keys (groups) and their correspondent from B:B. It returns starting from "D1", but it can be easily adapted to return wherever you need:

```
Sub TransposePerArticles()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrfin, arrIt
  Dim i As Long, maxCols As Long, totRows As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = Sheets("POSITION")
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of the range to be processed
  
  arr = ws.Range("A1:B" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
  
  'extract unique keys (from A:A) and their necessary iterms:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)  'iterate between the array rows
    If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then 'if not an empty row:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'if dictionary key does not exist (yet)
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(1, CStr(arr(i, 2))) 'create  the dictionary key and
                                                          'place a item array. its first element
                                                          'is the number of respective key occurrences
                                                          'the scond one is the first element from B:B
            If maxCols = 0 Then maxCols = 1  'it extracts the maximum number of items of the key with maximum
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))  'place the item array in an array (you cannot modify an array in a dict)
            arrIt(0) = arrIt(0) + 1  'increment its first element
             If maxCols < arrIt(0) Then maxCols = arrIt(0) 'maximum number of necessary columns
             arrIt(1) = arrIt(1) & "|" & CStr(arr(i, 2))   'place the item from B:B separated by "|"
             dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place back the array as the dictionary item
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  
  'extract the final array necessary number of rows:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    totRows = totRows + dict.Items()(i)(0) 'it adds the first array elements value
  Next i
  
  ReDim arrfin(1 To totRows + dict.count, 1 To maxCols) 'ReDim the array to its NECESSARY number of elements
  Dim j As Long, k As Long: k = 1 'k keeps the final array rows to be updated number
  
  'Load the final array with the processed return:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1 'iterate between the dictionary elements
     arrIt = Split(dict.Items()(i)(1), "|") 'extract in an array the respective items (1 - the second)
     For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt)             'iterate between the extracted array elements
        arrfin(k, j + 1) = dict.keys()(i)   'place the key on the first group row (A1, B1 etc.)
        arrfin(k + 1, j + 1) = arrIt(j)     'place the elements extracted from B:B
     Next j
     k = k + 3 'to include an empty row, too
  Next
  
  'drop the final array content, at once and format the range to keep "0001"
  'instead of "1", as Excel automatically deduces:
  With ws.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arrfin), UBound(arrfin, 2))
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .value = arrfin
  End With
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

It looks complicated, but it is not, if you will try understanding it. Not using the clipboard at all makes it very fast.

If something not clear enough, even if I tried commenting each code line, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for your time.